# How to make a GitHub mirror to Bitbucket?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have a repo that I've cloned from GitHub and want to have a mirror of this repo on BitBucket. Is there is any way how to do it? Something like having two origin in the repo as I think.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You could simply add a second remote:

```
git remote add bitbucket /url/to/am/empty/bitbucket/repo
```

and push everything to bitbucket:

```
git push --mirror bitbucket
```

You can actually [pull from or push to multiple remotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/849308/6309) from your local repo.

---

Update 2020:

As noted below in [Rahulmohan Kolakandy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8418070/rahulmohan-kolakandy)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47206002/6309), if you are talking about an on-premise BitBucket server (as opposed to bitbucket.org), then you can take advantage of [BitBucket Server Smart Mirroring](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/smart-mirroring-776640046.html).

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551929/how-to-make-a-github-mirror-to-bitbucket/21554759#comment109271794_21554759) by **[V-Q-A NGUYEN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2599865/v-q-a-nguyen)**:

[**BitBucket Server Smart Mirroring**](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/smart-mirroring-776640046.html) ([introduced originally in 2016](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/atlassian-introduces-smart-mirroring-to-accelerate-git-transactions-in-bitbucket/), and [Oct. 2017 for BitBucket Server](https://sdtimes.com/atlassian/atlassian-updates-bitbucket-server-bamboo-support-devops-workflows/))

> **is only available for customers with an active Bitbucket Data Center license**

Comment: BitBucket Server Smart Mirroring feature is only available for customers with an active Bitbucket Data Center license

Comment: @V-Q-ANGUYEN Thank you, good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 9):

The method explained here is better https://stackoverflow.com/a/12795747/988941

`git remote set-url origin --add https://bitbucket.org/YOU/YOUR_REPO.git`

Recent version of git handle multiple URLs in the same origin ;)

Answer (score 4):

With Bitbucket Server, you can use ScriptRunner https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1213250/scriptrunner-for-bitbucket-server-stash?hosting=server&tab=overview

Full Disclosure: I work for them :)

Answer (score 3):

you no longer have to create these mirror links. Bitbucket has come up with this concept of smart mirror which does a real time sync to your mirror server.

More read here
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/smart-mirroring-776640046.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good point (+1) I have included this feature in my answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check the following (copy pasted from links below) ;

From [How to properly mirror a git repository](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/05/how-to-properly-mirror-a-git-repository/), you can use

```
git clone --mirror git@example.com/upstream-repository.git

cd upstream-repository.git

git push --mirror git@example.com/new-location.git
```

Or you can follow  [Duplicating a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/);

Open Terminal and create a bare clone of the repository.

```
git clone --bare https://github.com/exampleuser/old-repository.git
```

Mirror-push to the new repository.

```
cd old-repository.git
git push --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git
```

Remove the temporary local repository you created in step 1.

```
cd ..
rm -rf old-repository.git
```