# Push all remote tracking branches to new remote?

Tags: git

I have cloned my repo and would like to push all my remote branches (origin/*) to a new remote which I configured. I have tried:

```
git push anotherRemote --all
```

but it only pushes the ones that I made a local copy from. When I type:

```
git branch -r
```

I see all the branches located on my other remote (which I have not created local copies of). How to I push those to my `anotherRemote` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GitHub make mirror to Bitbucket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551929/github-make-mirror-to-bitbucket)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply specify explicitly what you want to push where:

```
git push anotherRemote refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*
```

This will take all remote branches of origin and push them as normal branches on the other remote. (Verify with `git fetch anotherRemote; git branch -rv`.)

Beware of the `--mirror` option unless you *really* understand what it does!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--mirror` option to `git push`. From [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push.html):

> Instead of naming each ref to push, specifies that all refs under `refs/` (which includes but is not limited to `refs/heads/`, `refs/remotes/`, and `refs/tags/`) be mirrored to the remote repository. Newly created local refs will be pushed to the remote end, locally updated refs will be force updated on the remote end, and deleted refs will be removed from the remote end. This is the default if the configuration option `remote.<remote>.mirror` is set.

See also [How to make a GitHub mirror to Bitbucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551929/github-make-mirror-to-bitbucket).

Comment: Here they warn against using --mirror. https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/54235/importing-an-existing-repository-into-stash

Comment: @u123, that appears to warn against using `--mirror` with `git clone`. I'm suggesting to use it with `git push`.

Comment: hm git push anotherRemote --mirror does not have any effect. I still do not see the remote branches on my anotherRemote